# Unable to save data from Django form

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to save data from a form into a database table named 'ModuleNames', but it is updating 'ModuleType' column of foreign(instance) table.

I created an instance of said foreign table because it was giving a different error about assigning value to the foreign key column and from various blogs I learned that the instance is needed, but it seems it is not the correct way. I am really unsure what to do now?

models.py

```
class ModuleTypes(models.Model):
    ModuleType = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ModuleDesc = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    Sort = models.SmallIntegerField()
    isActive = models.BooleanField()
    slug = models.SlugField(('Type'), max_length=50, blank=True)

class Meta:
    app_label = 'zz'
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.slug = slugify(self.Type) 
    super(ModuleTypes, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class ModuleNames(models.Model):
    ModuleName = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ModuleDesc = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    ModuleSort = models.SmallIntegerField()
    isActive = models.BooleanField()
    ModuleType = models.ForeignKey(ModuleTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(('ModuleName'), max_length=50, blank=True)

class Meta:
    app_label = 'zz'
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.status
```

forms.py

```
class ModuleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    moduleName = forms.CharField(label='Module Name', max_length=50)
    ModuleDesc = forms.CharField(max_length = 256)
    ModuleSort = forms.IntegerField()
    isActive = forms.BooleanField()
    ModuleType = forms.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    model = ModuleNames
    fields = ('moduleName','ModuleDesc','ModuleSort','isActive','ModuleType')
```

views.py

```
def addmodule(request,moduletype):
    template_name = 'module.html'
    modules = ModuleNames.objects.all()
    listmodules = ModuleTypes.objects.get(ModuleType=moduletype)
    modules = ModuleNames.objects.filter(ModuleType_id=listmodules)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        args = {'modules': modules }
        return render(request,template_name, args)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModuleForm(request.POST, instance=ModuleTypes.objects.get(ModuleType=moduletype))
    if form.is_valid():
        #form.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken', None)It is annoying this part because of that i put in comment.
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.save()
    else:
        #raise error
    return render(request, template_name, {'modules': modules})
```

Thanks

I don't get any error by above code but i get below error when not using 'instance' of foreign table

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/module/nav-tab/new

Django Version: 2.1.3
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['Comp',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/cem/Documents/Projects/DevComp/Comp/views.py" in addmodule
133.         if form.is_valid():

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
185.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
180.             self.full_clean()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
383.         self._post_clean()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
398.             self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in construct_instance
 60.             f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in save_form_data
854.         setattr(instance, self.name, data)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __set__
210.                     
self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,

Exception Type: ValueError at /module/nav-tab/new
Exception Value: Cannot assign "1": "ModuleNames.ModuleType" must be a "ModuleTypes" instance.
```

Comment: please include the last part of any errors/traceback, that way we may know what your error is directly without hunting for it

Comment: also consider changing all your assignments to be more readable - e.g `ModuleSort = forms.IntegerField()` should be `module_sort = forms.IntegerField()`

Comment: @JackHerer thanks for editing. When i use code above, it doesn't give any error but it is saving data into the ModuleTypes table instead of ModuleNames table. I can put error what i get when removing 'instance' part.

Comment: any errors may be helpful, I am just trying to read your code but your code style is very different to mine

Comment: yes because i am new in django and still learning. I added error code.

Comment: I moved from Django to Flask because Django was so hard to learn and I was always seeing these kinds of things. As I read your code I am spotting some mistakes such as `fields = ('moduleName', ... )` should `moduleName` not be `ModuleName`? which is why I would suggest using proper python conventions, class names are `CamelCase` and assignments `the_one = 1` and functions `def with_underscores(self):` are usually done with underscores. I think you just have a mistake because you cannot follow what is what in your code, try to change them and you may find your error

Comment: `form = ModuleForm(request.POST, instance=ModuleTypes.objects.get(ModuleType=moduletype))` - I think this may be where your error is, also I think having two tables with the same column names with foreign keys will be problematic, again this would mean renaming your column assignments.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
form = ModuleForm(request.POST, instance=ModuleTypes.objects.get(ModuleType=moduletype))  # <-- here
```

You are passing `ModuleTypes` as instance where your should be passing `ModuleNames` model instance. So you should update the form like this:

```
form = ModuleForm(request.POST, instance=ModuleNames.objects.get(ModuleType=listmodules))  # listmodules is a ModuleType object
```

Also minor refactoring:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ModuleForm(request.POST, instance=ModuleNames.objects.get(ModuleType=listmodules))
    if form.is_valid():  # <-- valid check in post request
        #form.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken', None)It is annoying this part because of that i put in comment.
        post = form.save()
return render(request, template_name, {'modules': modules})
```

And also please use `snake_case` in Model Field(Model class's attribute) definitions as per [PEP8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: I changed with this;`form = ModuleForm(request.POST, instance=ModuleNames.objects.get(ModuleType=listmodules))` but  It give this error; `ModuleNames matching query does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

```
install django==2.2.28, mssql-django==1.1.3
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.